# Не применяются параметры при вызове query.prepare()

Tags: c++, sql, qt

```
 q.prepare("call new_employee(:new_login,"
                  ":first_name,"
                  ":last_name,"
                  ":phone_number,"
                  ":email,"
                  "'2',"
                  ":hashed_password);");

    q.bindValue(":new_login", login);
    q.bindValue(":first_name", firstName);
    q.bindValue(":last_name", secondName);
    q.bindValue(":phone_number", phone);
    q.bindValue(":email", mail);
    q.bindValue(":hashed_password", hashing(password));

    q.exec();
```

`new_employee` - процедура по созданию нового юзера. Процедура принимает в кач-ве параметров , 6 varchar-ов и один integer. Все параметры `login`, `first_name` ... берутся из `lineEdit` из ui(методом `text()`), соответственно имеют тип `qstring`.

`query.lastQuery()` показывается примерное следующее

```
"CALL new_employee(?,?,?,?,?,'2',?);"
либо 
"call new_employee(:new_login,:first_name,:last_name,:phone_number,:email,'2',:hashed_password);"
```

в зависимости от того какой синтаксис выбираю для написания запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

окей, не юзайте qstring как аргументы в prepare,
так же не юзайте такой синтаксис

```
query.prepare(QString("sql-запрос").arg(login).arg(firstName).arg(secondName));
```

так как вы форматируете всю строку, идущую в виде запроса в бд, *в непонятный для нее qstring*, не со всеми бд так, но для postgres это верно, либо же это просто в моем случае так произошло.

- не уверен в информации, но к другому выводу я прийти не смог

Comment: избегайте такого. это плохая практика. пользователь с именем ```');drop database dnname;``` не даст соврать

Comment: Реализована проверка на sql injection в отдельных функциях при вводе всех данных от юзера. Но спасибо, что дали знать, т.к вещь действительно важная)